# Compare two lists and return Boolean

Tags: elixir

I have two lists

```
 list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
 list2 = [3,4,5]
```

If all the elements in list2 present in list1. It should return `true` otherwise it will return `false`.

I considered Enum.member? but it compare single element with the list not the complete list.

Any other way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `MapSet.subset?/2` here:

```
iex(1)> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
iex(2)> list2 = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
iex(3)> MapSet.new(list2) |> MapSet.subset?(MapSet.new(list1))
true
iex(4)> list2 = [3, 4, 5, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 9]
iex(5)> MapSet.new(list2) |> MapSet.subset?(MapSet.new(list1))
false
```

This will run in `O(n log n)` time as opposed to `Kernel.--/2` which runs in `O(n^2)`. (This won't make a significant difference for small lists though.)

Comment: Thanks didn't know about MapSet methods.

Comment: It may be worth noting that by definition you can't have duplicate elements in your list if you use MapSet.  I don't know if that's a concern for the OP or not but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `length(list2 -- list1)` is equal to zero

Comment: Thanks. Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MapSet.equal?](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html#equal?/2):

```
iex(1)>     MapSet.equal?(MapSet.new(list1), MapSet.new(list2))
true
iex(2)> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
iex(3)> list2 = [3,4,5]
[3, 4, 5]
iex(4)> MapSet.equal?(MapSet.new(list1), MapSet.new(list2))
false
```